# JSON Parsing with Volley and GSON

Tags: java, android, json, gson, android-volley

I'm trying to parse json from this url

http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=09100&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7&lang=tr

I created pojo for gson and I added volley based class into my app.

I want to parse json objects into my listview with my custom adapter

my Volley+Gson Request:

```
  private void loadAPI(){
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());

        String url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=09100&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7&lang=tr";
        //showDialog();
        GsonRequest<WeatherItem> myReq = new GsonRequest<WeatherItem>(
                Request.Method.GET,
                url,
                WeatherItem.class,
                mOnWeatherResponseLister(),
                mOnErrorListener());


        mRequestQueue.add(myReq);

    }

    private Response.Listener<WeatherItem> mOnWeatherResponseLister() {
  ForecastFragment 108 =  return new Response.Listener<WeatherItem>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(WeatherItem response) {
                try {
                    Log.d("Json Response", response.list.toString());
                    Log.d("Json Response", response.list.get(0).dt.toString());
                    Log.d("Json Response", response.list.get(0).weather.get(0).description.toString());
                    Log.d("Json Response",WeatherUtility.formatMinTemperature(getActivity(),response.list.get(0).temp.min));
                    for (int i = 0; i<=response.list.size()-1 ; i++) {


                        WeatherResp weatherResp = new WeatherResp();
                        Weather weather= new Weather();
                          weatherResp.weather.set(i,weather).setIcon(WeatherUtility.getIconResourceForWeatherCondition(response.list.get(i).weather.get(i).id));
                Fragment 121 = weatherResp.setDt((response.list.get(i).dt));
                          weatherResp.weather.set(i,weather).setDescription(response.list.get(i).weather.get(i).description.toString());
                          weatherResp.temp.setMin(Double.valueOf(WeatherUtility.formatMinTemperature(getActivity(), response.list.get(i).temp.min)));
                          weatherResp.temp.setMax(Double.valueOf(WeatherUtility.formatMaxTemperature(getActivity(), response.list.get(i).temp.max)));

                        arrItemList.add(weatherResp);
                    }

                    mListView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);
                    mForecastAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                //hideDialog();
            }

            ;
        };
    }
```

Pojos:

```
public class WeatherItem {

    public String cod;
    public String message;
    public int cnt;
    public ArrayList<WeatherResp> list;
    public String getCod() {
        return cod;
    }

public class WeatherResp {

    public Long dt;
    public Temp temp;
    public Float pressure;
    public Integer humidity;
    public ArrayList<Weather> weather;
    public Float speed;
    public Float deg;
    public Integer clouds;

public class Weather {

    public Integer id;
    public String main;
    public String description;
    public int icon;
public class Temp {


    public Float day;
    public Double min;
    public Double max;
    public Double night;
    public Double eve;
    public Double morn;
```

My Adapter:

```
public class WeatherAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


private Context ctx;
private ArrayList<WeatherItem> weatherItems;
private ArrayList<WeatherResp> arrItemList;

public WeatherAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<WeatherResp> weatherResps) {

    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.arrItemList = weatherResps;
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    public ImageView iconView;
    public TextView dateView;
    public TextView descriptionView;
    public TextView highTempView;
    public TextView lowTempView;
    //public TextView humidity;
    //public TextView pressure;


    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        iconView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_icon);
        dateView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_date_textview);
        descriptionView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_forecast_textview);
        highTempView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_high_textview);
        lowTempView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_low_textview);

        v.setTag(this);
    }
}

/**
 * Cache of the children views for a forecast list item.
 */
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return weatherItems.size();

}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return weatherItems.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertview, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    ViewHolder holder;
    View v = convertview;

    if (v == null) {
        v = View.inflate(ctx, R.layout.list_items_forecast, viewGroup);
        holder = new ViewHolder(v);
        holder.iconView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_icon);
        holder.dateView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_date_textview);
        holder.descriptionView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_forecast_textview);
        holder.lowTempView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_low_textview);
        holder.highTempView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_high_textview);
        v.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }

    WeatherResp weatherResp1 = arrItemList.get(position);

    holder.iconView.setImageResource(weatherResp1.getWeather().get(position).getIcon());
    holder.dateView.setText(weatherResp1.getDt().toString());
    holder.descriptionView.setText(weatherResp1.getWeather().get(position).getDescription());
    holder.lowTempView.setText(WeatherUtility.formatMinTemperature(ctx, weatherResp1.getTemp().min));
    holder.highTempView.setText(WeatherUtility.formatMaxTemperature(ctx,weatherResp1.getTemp().max));
    return v;
}
```

When I run my logcat is:

```
W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
W/System.err﹕ at com.hasan.basan.fragment.ForecastFragment$1.onResponse(ForecastFragment.java:121)
W/System.err﹕ at com.hasan.basanfragment.ForecastFragment$1.onResponse(ForecastFragment.java:108)
W/System.err﹕ at com.hasan.basan.utility.GsonRequest.deliverResponse(GsonRequest.java:78)
W/System.err﹕ at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Where is my mistake? Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at this answer -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/31386256/1177959

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your exception is thrown from here:
`com.hasan.basan.fragment.ForecastFragment$1.onResponse(ForecastFragment.java:121)`
I can't see line numbers so i will try to guess why the exception has been thrown.

```
WeatherResp weatherResp = new WeatherResp();
Weather weather= new Weather();
weatherResp.weather.set(i,weather).setIcon(WeatherUtility.getIconResourceForWeatherCondition(response.list.get(i).weather.get(i).id));
```

On 3rd line of code you are accessing varialbe `weatherResp.weather`. I have 2 explanations.

1. Maybe you forgot to set new `Weather` instance to your `weatherResp` variable.
2. Maybe you forgot to initialize you `ArrayList` of `Weather` variables in default constructor of `WeatherResp` class.

Comment: I changed Weather like this public class Weather extends ArrayList<Weather> {
 and I added a constructor to WeatherResp     public WeatherResp(ArrayList<Weather> weather) {

        this.weather = weather;

    }

Comment: NPE gone but my listview not populated :(

Comment: when I debugging arrItemList = {java.util.ArrayList@3462362} size=0 I think it should be populated with weatherResp variables.

Comment: @HasanBasan did you find what variable is null then?

Comment: I have 4 model class and I want to populate my arraylist with instance of WeatherResp.